# python gspread not working on GAE

Tags: google-app-engine

I had a program that ran for years on Google App Engine. It was written in python and uses gspread. It suddenly stopped working on GAE and returns a 404. I tested it locally and it works fine.

Answer (score 0):

I’ve found this open [public issue tracker](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/196857020) where it seems it could be a similar issue than yours. I would suggest you add a comment in that public issue tracker explaining your issue.